# What cells are empty in given range

Tags: vba, excel

I have a given range which I get for empty numbers. I want to tell user which cells are empty. This is function:

```
Sub check()
'   Goal: check if there are any entry truth table cells for outputs
Dim outputsrange As range
Set outputsrange = range(inputnum + 1 & ":" & inputnum + outputnum)
If IsEmpty(outputsrange) Then
    MsgBox ("The following cells are empty:" & vbNewLine & emptycell)
Else
    Call makekmap
End If
End Sub
```

What do I put where "emptycell" is?

EDIT: new code, still doesn't run but has correct object definitions.

```
Sub check()
Dim outputsrange As range, emptycells As range
Set outputsrange = range(inputnum + 1 & ":" & cases)
Set emptycells = outputsrange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
If Not emptycells Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "The following cells are empty:" & vbNewLine & emptycells.Address
Else
    MsgBox ("No cells are empty")
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Check if the [Range.SpecialCells method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196157.aspx) with the **xlCellTypeBlanks** option reports blank cells and output the unioned [Range.Address property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837625.aspx) if they exist.

```
Dim inputnum As Long, outputnum As Long
Dim outputsrange As Range, mtCells As Range
inputnum = 1: outputnum = 6
Set outputsrange = Range(inputnum + 1 & ":" & inputnum + outputnum)
On Error Resume Next
Set mtCells = outputsrange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
On Error GoTo 0
If Not mtCells Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "The following cells are empty:" & vbNewLine & _
           mtCells.Address(0, 0)
Else
    Call makekmap
End If
```

Please note that cells containing formulas that return zero-length strings (e.g. `""` are not truly blank.

Alternate without On Error Resume Next

```
Dim inputnum As Long, outputnum As Long
Dim outputsrange As Range
inputnum = 1: outputnum = 6
Set outputsrange = Range(inputnum + 1 & ":" & inputnum + outputnum)
If CBool(Application.CountBlank(outputsrange)) Then
    MsgBox "The following cells are empty:" & vbNewLine & _
           outputsrange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Address(0, 0)
Else
    Call makekmap
End If
```

You will have to be careful with that because the worksheet's [COUNTBLANK function](https://support.office.com/en-au/article/countblank-function-c72134a2-695e-43ab-a3f3-714aa770f385) will count cells containing zero-length strings as blanks but the SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks) will not. Potentially, you could 
have a situation where you enter the MsgBox area but have nothing to report.

Comment: I've added a `On Error Resume Next` to skip over the assignment of a range that is nothing.

Comment: @Jeeped if working with `On Error Resume Next` you could skip the `mtCells`, switch the 2 if-actions and directly use `If outputsrange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks) Then`... having `Call makekmap` as true-part and `MsgBox "The following cells are empty:" & vbNewLine & outputsrange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Address(0, 0)` as `Else`... will do the same, but saves at least one variable...

Comment: I'm pretty sure GoTo 0 is a very bad programming practice lol, but thank you very much. Even with Resume Next I still get runtime error 1004. I posted new version of code above, ideas?

Comment: @ThomasShera - You are going to get a `1004` error if you attempt to set a range object to nothing. If there are no truly blank cells in outputsrange then `outputsrange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)` is nothing and you need an `On Error Resume Next` to get past it.

Comment: @DirkReichel - That sounds like it should work to identify thing. I hate working with On Error Resume Next. I've never been of a mind that you have to break something to see if it is there.

Comment: @Jeeped it is more like: **IF** I have to use `On Error Resume Next` i'll do it in a nasty way... having a *can never be true*-condition which can pop an error and then enters the True-part :P

Comment: Worth noting that `SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)` will not count empty cells outside of the sheet's `UsedRange`, so it's possible for `CountBlank()` to be >0 but for SpecialCells to still error with "No cells found"

Answer (score 2):

A different way to avoid errors:

```
Sub check()
  Dim outputsrange As Range, runner As Variant
  Set outputsrange = Range(inputnum + 1 & ":" & inputnum + outputnum).CurrentRegion
  For Each runner In outputsrange.Formula
    If Len(runner) = 0 Then
      MsgBox "The following cells are empty:" & vbNewLine & _
      outputsrange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Address(0, 0)
      Exit Sub
    End If
  Next
  Call makekmap
End Sub
```

**EDIT**

Taking the answer from Jeeped and the comment from Tim Williams you could merge it with my solution to:

```
Sub check()
  Dim outputsrange As Range, runner As Variant
  Set outputsrange = Range(inputnum + 1 & ":" & inputnum + outputnum).CurrentRegion
  If Application.CountBlank(outputsrange) Then
    MsgBox "The following cells are empty:" & vbNewLine & _
      outputsrange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Address(0, 0)
    Exit Sub
  End If
  Call makekmap
End Sub
```

Should be the fastest way to get what you want and also not pop any errors as log as the `outputsrange` itself is valid.